# disallowed characters using mark, equal, and, semicolon

Tags: php, regex, codeigniter, uri

Hi I would like to access this link at the end of the link but 
An Error Was Encountered
The URI you submitted has disallowed characters.

I need this to get a lightbox using iframe working

```
?iframe=true&width=1000&height=500
```

I tried this `$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%.:_\?=-';`

need to add the question mark, equal, and, semicolon

any help?

Answer (score 0):

In the actual URL you should be using `&` to separate arguments (and `&amp;` when displaying them in XHTML). However, the `;` should not be invalid because it is a legal GET param separator as well.

The regex you have in your question should permit semi colons if you change it to...

```
$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%.:_\?=-;';
```

That is supposing the above string is substituted into a character range, e.g. `[...]`.

Comment: Tq but it went wrong preg_match() [function.preg-match]: Compilation failed: range out of order in character class at offset 23

Comment: the link I used was, it went wrong because of the filename it has bracket and all other symbols http://localhost/disctarra/index.php/front/play_stream/Anggun_mimpi1.mp3?iframe=true&width=1000&height=500 and get rid of the semicolon because it went wrong... Thank Alex

Answer (score 0):

Why do you use `&amp;` in the URL? The `&` by itself is URL-safe. i.e.

```
?iframe=true&width=1000&height=500
```

Assuming a WYSIWYG editor or something is spitting out the `&` as `&amp;`, **you should try and prevent it from doing this**.

After all, you don't want the url to be interpreted as `iframe=true` and `amp;width=1000` etc.